# Flutter Sliding Up panel

Tags: flutter

The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' for sliding up panel feature of PROFILE page for flutter program

```
  // Panel Body
 SingleChildScrollView _panelBody(ScrollController controller) {
   double hPadding = 40;
   return SingleChildScrollView(
               controller: controller,
               physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
               child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: hPadding),

                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                                             ^ context is the one that sending error signals which is The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. I imported the dart.js that it recommended yet it did not fix the error
                    )
                  ],
               ),
             );
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to import dart:js, could please share the full code along with package link you are using

Answer (score 0):

Add context in the _panelBody function

```
SingleChildScrollView _panelBody(ScrollController controller, BuildContext context) { // <----HERE
```

Then wherever you use method _panelBody use as below code

```
_panelBody(controller,context)
```

Comment: Thanks sir great help! thank you but I've been struggling in understanding this block of code can you elaborate more of it's function? thanks if ya can!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the buildContext in the _panelBody function.

```html
 SingleChildScrollView _panelBody(ScrollController controller, BuildContext context) {
   double hPadding = 40;
   return SingleChildScrollView(
               controller: controller,
               physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
               child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: hPadding),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                    )
                  ],
               ),
             );
 }
```

And call the widget as

```
_panelBody(controller, context)
```